# splitting version string until found

Tags: go

Sort of went down the rabbit hole on this one:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type apps []app

type app struct {
    version string
}

type releases []release

type release struct {
    name     string
    platform string
}

func main() {

    var versions releases
    versions = append(versions, release{name: "apple", platform: "3.14.15"})
    versions = append(versions, release{name: "orange", platform: "3.14.15.13"})
    versions = append(versions, release{name: "pear", platform: "3.14.19"})

    var test apps
    test = append(test, app{version: "3.14.15.5.123.2"}) // should map to apple
    test = append(test, app{version: "3.14.15.13.123"})  // should map to orange
    test = append(test, app{version: "3.14.15.19.12"})   // should map to pear

    for _, r := range test {
        fmt.Printf("Version %s is called: %s\n", r.version, "?")
    }

}
```

I'm trying to achieve the following output:

```
Version 3.14.15.5.123.2 is called: apple
Version 3.14.15.13.123 is called: orange
Version 3.14.15.19.12 is called: pear
```

I was thinking some sort of string search, slice, search, slice loop until i could find a match? is there an easier way?

Comment: Shouldn't those be 3, 14, 15, 9, 26, 53, 589, 73, 8, 26, 43, 38... :-)

Comment: yeah i missed that opportunity - how could i ? :) well spotted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to make so many lookups, then you can build an index and search in it. This way a search would take optimally maximum O(n) where n is the length of the version you are searching.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sort"
    "strings"
)

type apps []app

type app struct {
    version string
}

type releases []release

type release struct {
    name     string
    platform string
}

var index map[string]string

func BuildIndex(r releases) {
    sort.Slice(r, func(i, j int) bool { return r[i].platform < r[j].platform })
    index = make(map[string]string)
    for _, release := range r {
        s := ""
        for _, rn := range release.platform {
            s += string(rn)
            if strings.HasSuffix(s, ".") {
                continue
            }
            if _, found := index[s]; !found {
                index[s] = release.name
            }
        }
    }
}

func FindInIndex(v string) string {
    for {
        if name, found := index[v]; found {
            return name
        }
        v = v[:len(v)-1]
        if v == "" {
            break
        }
    }
    return ""
}

func main() {
    var versions releases
    versions = append(versions, release{name: "apple", platform: "3.14.15"})
    versions = append(versions, release{name: "orange", platform: "3.14.15.13"})
    versions = append(versions, release{name: "pear", platform: "3.14.19"})

    BuildIndex(versions)

    var test apps
    test = append(test, app{version: "3.14.15.5.123.2"}) // should map to apple
    test = append(test, app{version: "3.14.15.13.123"})  // should map to orange
    test = append(test, app{version: "3.14.19.12"})      // should map to pear

    for _, r := range test {
        fmt.Printf("Version %s is called: %s\n", r.version, FindInIndex(r.version))
    }

}
```

Comment: It outputs `Version 3.14.15.5.123.2 is called: orange` https://play.golang.org/p/7e4Uckascl0

Comment: @mh-cbon Thanks for pointing it out. I've fixed the code.

Answer (score 3):

You have to find the longest prefix in the releases type. For this you can implement a func like this one:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

type apps []app

type app struct {
    version string
}

type releases []release

type release struct {
    name     string
    platform string
}

func (r releases) FindName(version string) string {
    result := ""
    max := 0
    for _, release := range r {
        if strings.HasPrefix(version, release.platform) {
            if max < len(release.platform) {
                max = len(release.platform)
                result = release.name
            }
        }
    }
    return result
}

func main() {

    var versions releases
    versions = append(versions, release{name: "apple", platform: "3.14.15"})
    versions = append(versions, release{name: "orange", platform: "3.14.15.13"})
    versions = append(versions, release{name: "pear", platform: "3.14.19"})

    var test apps
    test = append(test, app{version: "3.14.15.5.123.2"}) // should map to apple
    test = append(test, app{version: "3.14.15.13.123"})  // should map to orange
    test = append(test, app{version: "3.14.19.12"})      // should map to pear

    for _, r := range test {
        fmt.Printf("Version %s is called: %s\n", r.version, versions.FindName(r.version))
    }

}
```

Comment: Yeah, i can see i overthought this - thanks so much, this works great. I need to run this on a dataset of around 20k records, on a regular basis. 80% of the "lookups" will be the same, i'm thinking of creating a map index or something for lookup first.